# can i paste csv file data into excel as excel have already some format,

Tags: python

I have a CSV file and an excel file with some formats. I want to paste CSV file data into excel paste as value like excel copy paste. I want to do it using python

```
from pandas.io.excel import ExcelWriter
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv (r'E:\what\hello.csv',delimiter = ',',index_col=0,header=None)
out_path = "E:/what/dddd.xlsx"

with pd.ExcelWriter(out_path,engine='xlsxwriter') as ew:
        df.to_excel(ew, sheet_name='Sheet1',startcol=0,startrow=1,float_format=None)
        print('success')
```

Comment: please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a tutorial or discussion forum.

Comment: from pandas.io.excel import ExcelWriter
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv (r'E:\what\hello.csv',delimiter = ',',index_col=0,header=)
out_path = "E:/what/dddd.xlsx"

with pd.ExcelWriter(out_path,engine='xlsxwriter') as ew:
        df.to_excel(ew, sheet_name='Sheet1',startcol=0,startrow=1)
        print('success')

Comment: 1 2 3 4 5
01-07-2012 ram 100 200 300 400
01-07-2012 shayam 101 201 301 401
01-07-2012 ramu 102 202 302 402
01-07-2012 ttu 103 203 303 403
01-07-2012 dsfb 104 204 304 404
01-07-2012 dfewr 105 205 305 405
this is output

Comment: but I have an excel format so I want python paste CSV data into excel as paste as value

Comment: Copy the code and data and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k). - [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)